# How do I determine what subset sizes to use for recursive feature elimination (rfe) in the caret R package?

Tags: r, rfe

I have high dimensional data (p >> n) with approximately 250,000 predictors. I'm trying to use rfe in the caret package to perform feature selection. Is there a rule of thumb or is it just trial and error in regards to setting the subset sizes for rfe()?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.